# TYPO3 Extbase backend module wrong template

Tags: module, path, typo3, backend, extbase

I have just installed sample *extension* called [blog_example](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/blog_example) and i dont understand, that when I open the backend module, i got the frontend template (*blog_example/Resources/Private/Templates/Blog/index.html*) instead of backend template (*blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/Blog/index.html*).
When I add some text in the FE template, i really see it in backend module.

What can be wrong? It is clear installation of this sample extension, I didnt change anything.

In *blog_example/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.txt* is (about BE module):

```
module.tx_blogexample {
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
}
```

In *blog_example/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt* is (about BE module):

```
module.tx_blogexample {
    settings < plugin.tx_blogexample.settings
    persistence < plugin.tx_blogexample.persistence
    view < plugin.tx_blogexample.view
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_blogexample.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_blogexample.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_blogexample.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

I am really confused.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you included the static TS templates?

Comment: No I havent, now it works! thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - do not forget to include static TS templates in Template configuration. 
Thanks to Michael.